# How to fix ‘Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in’ and ‘Trying to g... 'icon' of non-object in' error in php and discord API

Tags: php, discord.js

I explain my problem: I want the user to see these discord servers, so I retrieve the information with "https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds"
but by decoding the file and using that `$guild->id` and `$guild->icon` I have it's errors

> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\connected.php on line 102
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'icon' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\connected.php on line 102

So if you can help me, it's very cool

```
<?php

//...Other code...

$url="https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}")
));

$test = (curl_exec($ch));
      echo $test;  // for know if it's work i echo the json file

$guild = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

curl_close($ch); 

echo "<img height='145' width='145' src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/{$guild->id}/{$guild->icon}.png' />"; //img guilds

?>
```

Comment: You say `json_decode()` with the second parameter `true`, so it becomes an array and not an object.

Comment: ok now , the variable is not defined Undefined property: stdClass::$id,stdClass::$icon

Comment: `var_dump($guild);` and check that you're checking the correct indexes/properties.

Comment: `var_dump($guild)` return `object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["global"]=> bool(false) ["message"]=> string(27) "You are being rate limited." ["retry_after"]=> int(751) } ` so i think something is missing

Comment: You've made too many requests, so you're being rate limited by Discord. Try again in 751 seconds.

Comment: Oh, it's true, oups

Comment: i have tested now but it's same problem "You are being rate limited."...

Comment: That's something you'll need to ask Discord about. They're rejecting your request because you (or someone on the same IP/with the same tokens?) are making too many requests.

Comment: so now I can not do anything except go ask to discord ??

Comment: Well, the response you get from the API is pretty clear - you are being rate limited, meaning that there are too many requests - https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits -- you can't overwrite that. You need to figure out why you are rate-limited, and work around that limit.

Comment: One thing you can do while waiting for the rate limit to be resolved is make your code detect errors - before extracting the data, check that the response was what you expected, and log any error messages if it wasn't. Meanwhile, I've voted to close this question as "can no longer be reproduced", since the problem isn't really in the code shown.